# overridden equals method doesn't get called

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Base {

    protected int i = 0;

    public Base(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public Base(Base b) {
        this(b.i);
    }

    public Base foo() {
        return new Base(this);
    }
}


public class Sub extends Base {

    public Sub(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    public Sub(Sub s) {
        super(s.i * 2);
    }

    public Base foo() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((Sub) o).i == this.i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b1 = new Base(1);
        Base b2 = b1;
        Base b3 = b2.foo();
        Base b4 = new Sub(1);
        Base b5 = b4.foo();

        System.out.println(b1.equals(b3));
    }
}
```

The printed result is `false`. I've noticed the overridden method `equals(Object o)` never get caught and I suspect of course that this is the problem (Otherwise it would have printed `true`).

Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling `b1.equals(b3)` - `b1` is an instance of `Base`, not of `Sub`, so there's no way your overriding method can be called.

Heck, even `b3.equals(b1)` won't call anything on `Sub`, as `b3` refers to an instance of `Base` as well.

Only `b4` and `b5` refer to instances of `Sub`, so *only* `b4.equals(...)` or `b5.equals(...)` will call your overridden method. Additionally, because you're unconditionally casting within your `equals` method, `b4.equals(b1)` (for example) will throw an exception rather than returning `false`.

Answer (score 2):

**Let's see how your code (in main method) runs**

`Base b1 = new Base(1);` :- Creates new Base(1) Object and reference is `b1`. Lets call this Object as first object.

`Base b2 = b1;` :- Creates a Base type reference variable and assign the value of `b1` variable, So both b1 and b2 refers the same object (first object)

`Base b3 = b2.foo();` :- Creates a Base type reference variable `b3.` `foo()` method in first Base object is called and it returns a new Base object (second object) where it's i attribute value = first object's i attribute value

`Base b4 = new Sub(1);` :- Creates new Sub(1) Object and reference is `b4`. Lets call this Object as the Third object.

`Base b5 = b4.foo();` :- Creates a Base type reference variable `b5.` `foo()` method in third object (Sub) is called and it returns its own reference as a Base type. Sub can return its own reference as Base because Base is its Super Class.

`b1.equals(b3)` :- now you have called equals method of the object that `b1` referes. `b1` refers to a `Base` type object (First object). equals method of Base object is run. It has the default equals method. (overridden method is in the Sub object and this not a Sub Object.) Default equals method checks whether their hash codes are same. b1 is first object, b3 is the third object. so b1 and b3 are not equal.

So Output should be `false`.

There is no any overriding happening here.

If you changed the code as follows, You can get overridden output

```
Base b1 = new Sub(1);
Base b3 = b1.foo();
Base b4 = new Sub(1);
Base b5 = b4.foo();

System.out.println(b4.equals(b3));
```